# Authentication with ADAM. How to connect ApacheDS Studio with ADAM

Tags: active-directory, adam, apacheds

I am new with AD, I just intalled ADAM in my windows xp. Then I have created a new

instance following the steps, everything good:

---

```
Install a unique instance of ADAM.

Instance name: dash
Computers will connect to this instance of ADAM using the following ports:
LDAP port: 389
SSL port: 636

ADAM replication will use Negotiate authentication.

Store ADAM program files in the following location:
C:\WINDOWS\ADAM

Store ADAM data files in the following location:
C:\Archivos de programa\Microsoft ADAM\dash\data

Store ADAM data recovery information in the following location:
C:\Archivos de programa\Microsoft ADAM\dash\data

Run ADAM using the following account:
NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService

Set up the following account to administer ADAM:
JUANOX\Juano

Create the following application directory partition:
dc=xxxx,dc=com
```

---

After that I wanted to use ApacheDS Studio in order to connect to ADAM. But I faced this problem. Which user/password should I use for the connection?

Well, I tried "ADAM ADSI Edit" in order to create the connection, and I have this options:

```
Connection Name=dash
ServerName=localhost:389
DistinguishName or Naming Context:dc=xxxx,dc=com
The account of the currently logged on User
```

After use this configuration, I successfully created the connection

But I dont know the user/password!. I tried with JUANOX\Juano (this is my user in Windows) and "password", with Juano and password in ApacheDS Studio and nothing happens. I know that I dont need this app in order to admin ADAM (I could use ADAM ADSI Edit). But I need the information, since I want to manually connect to ADAM with an application that I am doing. I NEED THIS INFORMATION.

So?? what I am missing?

---

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, My mistake from the beggining. I erased the instance and I have created a new one, following this link:

http://www.coreblox.com/blog/tag/adam/

So, the solution was to create a admin user with "ADAM ADSI Edit". I was used to ApacheDS, and I always used the default user/pass. So, this was the mistake.

After creating the ADmin user, I was able to login in ApacheDS Studio Tool with the new user/pass :)

I hope this help some one else :)

Comment: Can you tell me how can I create an admin user using ADAM ADSI EDIT please ? 
I can't figure it out how! I am new to ADAM / AD LDS
I created a simple user (using powershell) but i can't find how can I grant admin access to that user. Or is there an other way to do it ? 
also how can I set a password to the admin user? 
 Thanks for your help